# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, esri

I downloaded `ArcGIS` Runtime SDK for `Xamarin (Quartz Beta)`.
On installing it out of the box in portable project I get following *error* :

> Could not install package 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms
>   100.0.0.1369-beta'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7

I tried to change the profile number but it doesn't seem to work. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code from their github project shows that they set up their projects using a shared code approach rather than a Portable Class Library. I'm not sure they designed their library with PCL support in mind.

In the beta forums, an esri employee answered this with regards to whether the SDK could support PCL:

> Unfortunately PCL isn't possible for the Runtime due to some of the native dependencies. We recommend using shared projects to share the code you otherwise would have put in a PCL.

Comment: This is correct. The ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET and Xamarin is for Shared Projects.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and source @germi